# Calculate account balance history in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get a balance history on the account using SQL. My table in **PostgreSQL** looks like this:

```
   id  sender_id    recipient_id           amount_money
   --- -----------  ---------------------- -----------------
   1   1            2                      60.00
   2   1            2                      15.00
   3   2            1                      35.00
```

so the user with id number 2 currently has 40 dollars in his account.
I would like to get this result using sql:

```
[60, 75, 40]
```

Is it possible to do something like this using sql in postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a rolling balance, you can `SUM` the amounts (up to and including the current row) based on whether the `id` was the recipient or sender:

```
SELECT id, sender_id, recipient_id, amount_money,
       SUM(CASE WHEN recipient_id = 2 THEN amount_money
                WHEN sender_id = 2 THEN -amount_money
           END) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS balance
FROM transactions
```

Output:

```
id  sender_id   recipient_id    amount_money    balance
1   1           2               60.00           60.00
2   1           2               15.00           75.00
3   2           1               35.00           40.00
```

If you want an array, you can use `array_agg` with the above query as a derived table:

```
SELECT array_agg(balance)
FROM (
  SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN recipient_id = 2 THEN amount_money
                  WHEN sender_id = 2 THEN -amount_money
             END) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS balance
  FROM transactions
) t
```

Output:

```
[60,75,40]
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aHQaYD3c62rcAL9iiZtWhw/0)

If you want to be more sophisticated and support balances for multiple accounts, you need to split the initial data into account ids, adding when the id is the recipient and subtracting when the sender. You can use `CTE`s to generate the appropriate data:

```
WITH trans AS (
  SELECT id, sender_id AS account_id, -amount_money AS amount
  FROM transactions
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, recipient_id AS account_id, amount_money AS amount
  FROM transactions
),
balances AS (
  SELECT id, account_id, ABS(amount),
         SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY id) AS balance
  FROM trans
)
SELECT account_id, ARRAY_AGG(balance) AS bal_array
FROM balances
GROUP BY account_id
```

Output:

```
account_id  bal_array
1           [-60,-75,-40]
2           [60,75,40]
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aHQaYD3c62rcAL9iiZtWhw/1)

Comment: I'd like to always put the first item 0 in the array. so I need: [0, 60,75,40]. Is it possible?

Comment: @reactdto2 perhaps https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aHQaYD3c62rcAL9iiZtWhw/2?

Comment: @reactdto2 no worries.